# How to add route so only traffic to 10.* are routed to VPN server?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

My local network is 192.168.0.0/16.
Gateway is 192.168.1.1
Host IP is 192.168.1.2 (**windows** 10)
VM IP is 192.168.1.5 (Linux)
Docker containers inside VM is 172.16.0.0/12

When I started Cisco VPN, the VPN network is 10.191.0.0/255.255.224.0.

route print

```
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     35
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.191.0.1     10.191.20.76      2
       10.191.0.0    255.255.224.0            on link      10.191.20.76    257
     10.191.20.76  255.255.255.255            on link      10.191.20.76    257
    10.191.31.255  255.255.255.255            on link      10.191.20.76    257
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0            on link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255            on link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            on link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.1  255.255.255.255            on link       192.168.1.2     36
      192.168.1.2  255.255.255.255            on link       192.168.1.2    291
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255            on link      192.168.56.1    281
   202.45.129.172  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     36
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            on link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            on link      192.168.56.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            on link       192.168.1.2    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0            on link      10.191.20.76    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            on link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            on link      192.168.56.1    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            on link       192.168.1.2    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255            on link      10.191.20.76    257
```

Permanent

```
192.168.5.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.1.5       1
   172.16.0.0      255.240.0.0      192.168.1.5       1
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.191.0.1       1
```

I can't remove routes 10.* as it's added by Cisco VPN client.
**How to add route so I can ping 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.5, 172.16.0.2?**

Comment: The routes appear to already be there. But, it appears your Cisco VPN client has probably taken over. It is dictated by VPN policy. If it's configured to not allow split tunneling you may have trouble. What happens if you disconnect the Cisco VPN then try to ping these endpoints?

Comment: If I disconnect VPN, sure it's working fine.

Comment: Unfortunately Cisco AnyConnect is not just a vpn client it is also a security product. If there is anything you can change it will be in the vpn settings, but whatever is dictated by policy can’t be changed. Your organization is blocking split tunneling for security reasons.

Comment: Look for a setting in the client called "split tunneling". otherwise, the vNic will send all traffic through the VPN. your organization may or may not allow you to modify this.

Comment: @FrankThomas there is also a setting called Local LAN Access that impacts this.